# Is there any way to pass the GraphQL query that arrives to Apollo Server on to another Apollo Server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, keystonejs

I'm writing an Apollo Server that is the GraphQL interface between my Apollo Client front and a variety of backend API's, some of which are REST and some of which will be GraphQL.

At the moment there is one GraphQL backend,a KeystoneJS CMS.

I find myself writing a *lot* of boilerplate to pass the GraphQL query (that is, mutation or query) that I receive from the front to the backend.  For instance, to get all `Article` entries in my Keystone CMS

```
type Query {
  allArticles(
    where: ArticleWhereInput
    search: String
    orderBy: String
    first: Int
    skip: Int
  ): [Article]
```

I receive the request in my interface resolver

```
// resolver.js
Query: {
        allArticles: (_, args, { dataSources }) => {
            const { where, search, orderBy, first, skip } = args || {};
            return dataSources.gqlApi.getArticles(where, search, orderBy, first, skip);
        },
```

then I pass it on to my GraphQL datasource

```
import { GraphQLDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-graphql';
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { Proposal, Article, Tag, ArticleWhereInput, TagWhereInput } from '../types/keystone';

const ARTICLES_QUERY = gql`
  query allArticles( $where: ArticleWhereInput
     $search: String
     $orderBy: String
     $first: Int
     $skip: Int) {
    allArticles(where: $where
     search: $search
     orderBy: $orderBy
     first: $first
     skip: $skip) {
      title
      text
      id

    }
  }
`;
```

where I have the method that the resolver calls

```
async getArticles(where: ArticleWhereInput,
                         search: String,
                         orderBy: String,
                         first: number,
                         skip: number): Promise<[Article]> {
        try {
            const response = await this.query(ARTICLES_QUERY, {
                query: ARTICLES_QUERY,
                variables: { where, search, orderBy, first, skip }
            });

            return response.data.allArticles;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but you can see it becomes cumbersome, particulary when the CMS changes. I was wondering whether there were ways to streamline the process.

I thought that perhaps the original GraphQL query is passed to the resolver, and that in some way I could just pass that along to the datasource and 'automate' the process a bit, but from the [Apollo Server docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/#resolver-function-signature) it doesn't seem so

[image]

I'm relatively new to GraphQL, so I'm a bit lost at this point on how to proceed down this avenue. Perhaps I could somehow get the original GraphQL query and other useful info 'further upstream' and place it in `context`?

It may be that -- owing to the definition of the task: to set up a GraphQL server that interfaces between a GraphQL front and another GraphQL server -- I just have to accept the boilerplate, or it may be that I'm missing the blindingly obvious.

For what it's worth, I have *no* control over the upstream server, that is, the KeystoneJS server, so things like Apollo Federation won't (as far as I know) work here.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do schema stitching. Schema stitching has been deprecated in favor of federation but is being maintained as a separate fork [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tools-fork).

Comment: @DanielRearden -- Worked fantastically!  That saves so much time and effort!  -- I assume that although it's deprecated it won't be eliminated in the future.  Should I be importing `makeExecutableSchema`, etc, from the fork, `graphql-tools-fork`, and not from  `graphql-tools`?

Comment: Yes -- the fork is being actively maintained while the maintainers of the original library are not accepting any PRs to fix issues related to schema stitching.